# 301 редирект в файле .htaccess для картинок в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

самописный сайт заменил на проект Laravel, изменилась папка картинок и соответственно адреса. Как сделать 301 редирект в файле .htaccess который лежит в папке public? И заметьте редирект не только в другую папку, но и с http на https.

Было:

```
http://mysite.com/img/tovar/pic-1.jpg
```

Стало:

```
https://mysite.com/images/pic-1.jpg
```

Заранее спасибо. Очень нужно, боюсь ошибиться.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/img/tovar/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/images/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Гугл предлагает посмотреть, например, тут:
[301 редирект (переадресация) через .htaccess – на все случаи жизни](https://web-optimizator.com/301-redirekt-htaccess/) (Правило №16. Редирект с протокола http на https).

Comment: Почему-то не срабатывает. Выяснил в поддержке хостинга что у меня автоматически сервер перенаправляет с http на https ДО обработки файла. В общем в итоге поддержка хостинга мне посоветовала RedirectMatch 301 /img/tovar/(.*) https://mysite.com/images/$1. Так работает.